# Tendría vs Tiene

Tags: verbos, vocabulario

I am relatively new to Spanish, and have absolutely no idea as to what the difference between *tendría* and *tiene* is. Can someone please elaborate for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're both forms of 'tener' ('to have').

*tiene* is the present tense, usually translated as 'has'. E.g. 'el **tiene** un libro' - 'he **has** a book'. Only the third person singular has this form.

*tendría* (note the accent on the i) is the conditional tense. English doesn't have a special verb form for this tense, but a translation often involves the word 'would'. Both the first and third person singular have this form.

[Here](https://grammar.spanishintexas.org/verbs/conditional/) is an example from Spanish in Texas:

> **Tendría** que decir es un acento más pegado al mexicano… por la frontera.
>
> I **would have** to say it is an accent that is more similar to the Mexican one… because of the border.